# findstring method in listbox not working ? c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

trying to get a specific item in a list box which will then load new web page
getting error saying listbox doesnt have 'findString' method?

Am i possibly missing a using ?

```
    protected void lstVideos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the currently selected item in the ListBox.
    string curItem = lstVideos.SelectedItem.ToString();

    // Find the string in lstVideos.
    int index = lstVideos.FindString(curItem);
    // If the item was not found in lstVideos display a message box, otherwise select it in lstVideos.
    if (index == 1)
    {

    }
```

Comment: does the code compile? where do you get the exception exactly? post the entire exception please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you are trying is for windows form [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5et1818(v=vs.110).aspx) and not for asp.net `ListBox` control. You can simply use [SelectedIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property to get the selected index:-

```
int index = lstVideos.SelectedIndex;
```